# fitting the dataset with a model equation

Tags: fitting, dataset

I have a dataset.

```
dataset={{0., 0.}, {0.25, -1.423}, {0.5, -1.494}, {0.75, -1.498}, 
         {0.99, -1.505}, {1.24, -1.513}, {1.89, -1.512}, {2.48, -1.527}, 
         {3.09, -0.971}, {3.71, -0.731}, {4.33, -0.474}, {4.95, -0.294}, 
         {5.57, -0.168}, {6.19, -0.081}, {6.8, -0.018}, {7.42, 0.03}, 
         {8.04, 0.063}, {8.66, 0.071}, {9.9, 0.072}, {11.14, 0.069}, 
         {12.38, 0.06}}
```

I have to fit it with the following equation:
`y(x) := α/k + (x + 0.012) * α - x * 0.012 * α^2/y`

I have tried it in the following way:

```
y[x_] := α/k + (x + 0.012) α - x*0.012*α^2/y

fit = NonlinearModelFit[dataset, y[x], {{α, 0.2}, {k, 0.4}}, x]
```

But, I could not fit it.

Comment: Do you want to divide the `\[Alpha]^2` term by `k` ? It does not make sense to divide by `y` .

Comment: Your model `y[x]` is linear in `x`,  whereas your dataset shows a nonlinear behavior?

Comment: In the equation there is a y in the right side. y both left side and right side are same.  This equation is not a linear equation

Comment: You can solve for `y` first.

Comment: @pyne Though your model is implicit? If yes change `y` to `y[x]` and solve for y[x] to get an explicit model